# How to send array using base64 in PHP and cURL?

Tags: php, arrays

Right now I want to send an array but I am getting this error message:

`base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`

How to encode an array using base64_encode?

My current code looks like this:

```
$encoded_message = urlencode( base64_encode( $array ) );


    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . '/catch.php?string=' . $encoded_message ); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    curl_close($ch);
```

How to make an encoded string from an array so I can send it as a get parameter?

Comment: serialize() the array first

Comment: You can try to send it type json ( `json_encode()` http://php.net/json_encode ) and then `urlencode()` it if u send it with `$_GET`.

Answer (score 3):

**json_encode** it first
then **base64_encode**

and to read the parameter dont forget to base64_decode first, then to json_decode